# Симметричность матрицы

Tags: c++, матрицы

Завтра сдавать курсовую роботу. Моим заданием являются функции симметричности матрицы. Я давно сделала код, он работал, подходила к преподавателю за проверкой, она сказала, что симметричность не проверяется по транспонированной матрице. И она сделала мне симметричность по вертикали и сказала таким же образом делать по остальным. Я  сделала, но когда ввожу матрицу 123\111\321, то выдаёт везде несимметричность, хотя по горизонтали она симметрична. Вот код:

```
#include <cstdlib.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    int R[4][4];
    int i,j,k,n,p,q,tmp,sim,fl;
    cout<<"Введите размерность матрицы"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Введите матрицу:"<<endl;
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        for (j=0; j<n; j++)
        cin>>R[i][j];
    {cout<<"-------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<" Симметричность по вертикали: \n";
    fl=0;
   for (j=0; j<n/2; j++)
    {for (i=0; i<n; i++)

              if(R[i][n-1-j]!=R[i][j]){fl=1;break;}
    }


    if(fl==1)
    { cout<<" Матрица не симметрична \n";}
    else  cout<<" Матрица симметрична \n";
    }
    cout<<"-------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<" Симметричность по горизонтали: \n";

   fl=0;
   for (i=0; i<n/2; i++)
    for (j=0; j<n; j++)
       if(R[n-1-i][j]!=R[i][j]) {fl=1;break;}



    if(fl==1) cout<<" Матрица не симметрична \n";
    else  cout<<" Матрица  симметрична \n";
        cout<<"-------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"Симметричность по основной диагонали:\n";

    {
    fl=0;
   for (i=1; i<n; i++)
    for (j=i+1; j<n; j++)
       if(R[j][i]!=R[i][j]) {fl=1;break;}


    if(fl==1) cout<<" Матрица не симметрична \n";
    else  cout<<" Матрица  симметрична \n";
    }

   cout<<"-------------------------------"<<endl;
   cout<<" Симметричность по боковой диагонали \n";

   {q=n-1;

    for (i=0; i<(n-1); i++)
    {
        p=q;   
        for (j=0; j<(n-1-i); j++)
            {

              if(R[i+p][j+p]!=R[i][j]){fl=1;break;}

               p--;
            }
         q--;
     }

    if(fl==1) cout<<" Матрица не симметрична \n";
    else  cout<<" Матрица  симметрична \n";
    }

  getch();
  return 0;  }
```

Просьба - проверить, что не так и помочь исправить, потому что преподаватель уже душит. Делать по-своему не даст.

Мой первоначальный код:

```
#include <cstdlib.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    int R[4][4];
    int i,j,k,n,p,q,tmp,sim;
    cout<<"Введите размерность матрицы"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Введите матрицу:"<<endl;
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        for (j=0; j<n; j++)
        cin>>R[i][j];
    cout<<"Симметричность матрицы по главной диагонали: \n";
    cout<<"Транспонированная  матрица:\n";
    { for (i=1; i<n; i++)
        for (j=i+1; j<n; j++)
        {
            R[j][i]=R[i][j];

        }
      for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<n; j++) printf("%3d",R[j][i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    if(R[i][j]!=R[j][i])
    cout<<"Матрица не симметрична\n";
    else  cout<<"Матрица симметрична\n"; }

 
   cout<<" Симметричность матрицы по боковой диагонали: \n";
    cout<<" Транспонированная  матрица:\n";
   {q=n-1;

    for (i=0; i<(n-1); i++)
    {
        p=q;   
        for (j=0; j<(n-1-i); j++)
            {

              R[i+p][j+p]=R[i][j];

               p--;
            }
         q--;
     }
     for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<n; j++) printf("%3d",R[i+p][j+p]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    if(R[i][j]!=R[i+p][j+p])
    { cout<<" Матрица не симметрична \n";}
    else cout<<" Матрица симметрична \n";}

    cout<<"  Симметричность матрицы по вертикали:\n";
    cout<<" Транспонированная  матрица:\n";
   {

   for (j=0; j<n/2; j++)
    {{for (i=0; i<n; i++)

              R[i][n-1-j]=R[i][j];}
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<n; j++) printf("%3d",R[i][n-1-j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    if(R[i][j]!=R[i][n-1-j])
    { cout<<" Матрица не симметрична \n";}
    else  cout<<" Матрица симметрична \n";}
    cout<<" Симметричность матрицы по горизонтали: \n";
    cout<<" Транспонированная  матрица:\n";
   {

   for (i=0; i<n/2; i++)
    {


            {for (j=0; j<n; j++)

              R[j][n-1-i]=R[i][j];


            }

     }
     for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<n; j++) printf("%3d",R[j][n-1-i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    if(R[i][j]!=R[j][n-1-i])
    { cout<<" Матрица не симметрична \n";}
    else  cout<<" Матрица симметрична\n";}
  getch();
  return 0;  }
```

Знаю, что в первоначальном коде не правильный вывод.

Comment: 123\111\321 - **центральная симметрия**, а не осевая

Comment: Вообще-то **[Симметричной](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0) называют квадратную матрицу, элементы которой симметричны относительно главной диагонали**. Так что задание надо ставить как-то иначе. В конце концов, мало ли какое в таком случае определение термина *симметрия* можно использовать...

Comment: @MBo, я сейчас жёстко туплю, из-за того, что месяц бьюсь с этой программой, а всё никак. Материал по симметричностям должен преподаваться на Линейной Алгебре, на которой нам толком ничего не объяснили. Я облазила все сайты с этой темы, так что мозг кипит, как котёл в аду. Поэтому можете либо в самом коде подсказать, что не так или поподробней объяснить, то, что имели в виду.

Comment: @Harry, да я знаю про квадратную матрицу. Задание просто звучит "Функции симметричности матрицы".  Я сделала относительно главной, а она мне сказала, что нужно ещё относительно боковой, горизонтали и вертикали. Дурдом.

Comment: Если по аналогии для вертикальной симметрии, то код для горизонтальной симметрии работает. Только матрица должна быть 123/111/123.

Comment: @DmitryK, да по горизонтали говорит,  что симметрично,вы правы., а по остальным нет (как и нужно, я полагаю). А сам код правильный?

Comment: Как я понял, события развивались так (я немного усилил термины): "- Я сделала программу, она определяет симметирчность матрицы! - Ваша программа определяет в матрицах один вид симметрии. Добавьте аналогичные проверики для дргуих видов симметрии матриц, и всё будет супер!" Так что, вроде бы, задание понятное: придумать еще несколько видов симметрии матриц и добавить аналогичные блоки кода. при запуске все блоки кода отрботают, и выведутся все вимды симметрии, которыми обладает матрица.

Comment: @S.H., она изначально проверяет на симметричность и выводит виды симметрии, какими владеет. По крайней  мере мне сказали так сделать. Будь моя воля, я бы сделала иначе всё. Но не принимают, а я устала бегать за преподавателем. Так что, мне легче просто сделать как они хотят.

Comment: ну, если приведенный в ответе код решает Вашу проблему - всё ок! я так понял, что решает? (странно в наш век зума и дискорда бегать за преподавателем, если её можно доставать в чатике :-) )

Comment: Да, решает. Тоже думаю, что странно. Но это преподаватель лет так 50-60. Она предпочитает видеть всё в живую.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы проверял все в одном цикле (правда, тогда его придется делать по всем элементам):

```
enum Symmetry
{
    MDiag = 0x01,
    SDiag = 0x02,
    Horz  = 0x04,
    Vert  = 0x08,
    Centr = 0x10
};

int SymMatrix(int**R, int N)
{
    int sym = 0x1F;
    for(int r = 0; r < N; ++r)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < N; ++c)
        {
            if ((sym & MDiag) && (R[r][c] != R[c][r]))         sym &= ~MDiag;
            if ((sym & SDiag) && (R[r][c] != R[N-1-c][N-1-r])) sym &= ~SDiag;
            if ((sym & Horz ) && (R[r][c] != R[r][N-1-c]))     sym &= ~Horz;
            if ((sym & Vert ) && (R[r][c] != R[N-1-r][c]))     sym &= ~Vert;
            if ((sym & Centr) && (R[r][c] != R[N-1-r][N-1-c])) sym &= ~Centr;
        }
    }
    return sym;
}

void tell(int sym)
{
    if (sym == 0) cout << "Матрица несимметрична\n";
    else
    {
        cout << "Матрица симметрична:\n";
        if (sym & MDiag) cout << "    относительно главной диагонали\n";
        if (sym & SDiag) cout << "    относительно побочной диагонали\n";
        if (sym & Horz)  cout << "    относительно горизонтали\n";
        if (sym & Vert)  cout << "    относительно вертикали\n";
        if (sym & Centr) cout << "    центральносимметрична\n";
    }
}
```

А вот как это работает: https://ideone.com/w8z3xz

Comment: Ухты!  Спасибо большое!

Comment: Спасибо здесь имеет вид принятого ответа :)

Answer (score 0):

Комментируете ввод матрицы из консоли, пишете вот так и проверяете каждую из симметрий:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int R[4][4] = {
        { 1, 2, 3},
        { 2, 0, 2},
        { 1, 2, 3}
    };
    int n = 3;
```

Comment: просто его в комментарий трудно вставить - нечитаемо получается.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Проверила - вроде всё работает. Просто мне вынесли мозг с этой прогой. Спасибо ещё раз!